# Disk reading operation is performing very slow | Java Stream

Tags: java, performance, java-8, java-stream, filestream

I need to read images from a folder and generate checksum for them. There are about 330760 images. Following is the code:

```
package com.test;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;

public class FileTest2 {

    private void readFiles() throws IOException {
        try (Stream<Path> filePathStream = Files
                .walk(Paths.get("d:\\codebase\\images"))) {
            filePathStream.parallel().forEach(filePath -> {
                String checksumSHA256 = "";
                try {
                    checksumSHA256 = DigestUtils.sha384Hex(new FileInputStream(filePath.toString()));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {
                    System.out.println(checksumSHA256);
                    System.out.println(filePath);
                    System.out.println("\n");

                }
            });
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        FileTest2 fileTest = new FileTest2();
        fileTest.readFiles();
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Total Time took: " + (endTime - startTime) / 1000);
    }
}
```

It took about 36 minutes.

System configuration:

Cores: 8 
Memory: 32 GB (15-17 GB is free). Rest of the memory is being used by another server.

36 minutes are too much. Is there a way to improve performance?

Comment: It seems like it didn't really take that long as I can see all the entries/file name path in the text file. However, the code is still executing. Am I missed to close any resource here?

Comment: You started a thread pool, which is still active, even though it has nothing to do. It is just sitting there idle waiting for work. Why did you create a thread pool? Your code is not doing anything multi-threaded. Anyway, shut down the executor.

Comment: Why do you believe the program should "take all memory"? Your program isn't doing anything. --- Why did you create a question about code being slow, then not actually ask about slow code or even show that it is slow? Please **edit** the question and clean it up!!!

Comment: Yes. I missed to close the executor.

Comment: What do you mean my code is not doing anything? It's reading all the files/images from the file system and printing name on the console.

Comment: Why even bother with the thread pool?  Have you tried `filePathStream.parallel().forEach`?  Also, this isn't a proper benchmark.

Comment: @PuneetJain The code isn't doing anything that consumes a lot of memory. You're printing all the file names, one at a time, so only one name is in memory at the same time. You're not reading files (content), just their names, so why do you believe the code would be using a lot of memory?

Comment: Have you tried to use VisualVM or any other Java profiler to check memory consumption instead of Windows task manager? Also do you use `-Xms` key when starting your Java app?

Comment: @Ivan - Not yet. But I'm planning to use.

Comment: @JacobG.Haven't tried parallel. Can give it a try

Comment: Updated my code. Generating checksum for all the images.

Comment: @JacobG.I just finished trying with parallel and it took: 2086 seconds.

Comment: Why are you testing `Files.isRegularFile(filePath)` *after* you’ve calculated the checksum for it? Isn’t it a bit late to question that property? Besides that, it’s not a good idea to perform three individual print statements with a *parallel* stream, where every other thread could perform its own print statements in-between. Further, why are you going the old I/O detour, i.e. `new FileInputStream(filePath.toString())` instead of using `Files.newInputStream(filePath)`?

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out you do not terminate the executor. To see the actual times run the following

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    FileTest fileTest = new FileTest();
    fileTest.readFiles();

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Total Time took: "+ (endTime-startTime)/1000);
}
```

**Note**: at least from the bit of code you posted there is no reason to use an `ExecutorService`

Comment: Just updated my code. Generating checksum for all the images.

Comment: Please run the code I suggested and report the value of "Total Time took: "

Comment: I just finished with parallel and it took: 2086 seconds. 

filePathStream.parallel().forEach(filePath -> {}

Yet to try without parallel, but I'm sure it would be horrible,

Comment: Please comment out the println statements and report the value of "Total Time took: "

Comment: Also, with the implementation of sha you measure not only ithe time it takes to traverse the file system but also the time it takes to read each file

Comment: Okay. I'll comment out and try. Currently trying without parallel(). 

For SHA - Essentially, my code will generate sha for all the images and store them in a database. I need to run this code once a day. So trying to get the best performance I can.

I believe it will slow down more, once I persist SHA to database.

Comment: Took 9988 seconds without parallel(). Trying without println now.

Comment: 2137 seconds without println's and with parallel().

Comment: So about 7 msec. per file. You can improve things by using a BufferedInputStream